# ActionScript3. How to cast Embed MovieClip to MovieClip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have HintMenu.swf library with MovieClips :

```
    public class PopupMenuItem extends MovieClip {

    [Embed(source="HintMenu.swf", symbol="ExternalMovie")]
    private var woodButtonClass:Class;

    public var activeItemSkin:MovieClip;

    public function PopupMenuItem(
        activeItemSkin = new woodButtonClass();
    )
```

But on start, I receive the following Error :

```
[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed:
cannot convert energy.ui.alts.component.popup::PopupMenuItem_woodButtonClass@a7c0e19 to
flash.display.MovieClip.
```

I need to use it as MovieClip later. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can`t cast Embed MovieClip with 1 frame to MovieClip.
Cause of optimization reasons Flash IDE converts it to Sprite :

```
package {
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    [SWF(backgroundColor="0x333333")]
    public class Test_MultipleSwfEmbed extends Sprite{
        [Embed(source="swf/HintMenu.swf", symbol="button1")]
        private var oneFrameMovieClip:Class;

        [Embed(source="swf/HintMenu.swf", symbol="button2")]
        private var twoFramesMovieClip:Class;

        public function Test_MultipleSwfEmbed() {

            //"is MovieClip" = true, when > 1 frame
            traceType(new oneFrameMovieClip()); // false, true, true
            traceType(new twoFramesMovieClip()); // true, true, true
        }

        private function traceType(mc:*):void {
            trace(mc is MovieClip, mc is Sprite, mc is DisplayObjectContainer);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `as MovieClip`.

```
activeItemSkin = new woodButtonClass() as MovieClip;
```

You need to make sure that `woodButtonClass` is actually a `MovieClip`. If it is not then `activeItemSkin` will be null.

Comment: might have to wait until it is fully loaded also